# Funciones Ajax con sesiones no retornan valores

Tags: php, ajax, apache, wamp

Estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente, eh creado 2 VirtualHost con Wampserver, uno llamado ecuservicechile.lc y el otro que representa un subdominio portal.ecuservicechile.lc.

Ambos funcionan bien, excepto las peticiones Ajax que conllevan sesiones de por medio, ya que aquellas peticiones que no incluyen sesiones en el script PHP, las retorna correctamente.
Tengo los VirtualHost configurados de la siguiente forma

```
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ecuservicechile.lc
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/ecuservi"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/ecuservi/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portal.ecuservicechile.lc
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/ecuservi/portal"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/ecuservi/portal">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
            Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
            Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

En el siguiente archivo llamado creditos_disponibles.php, si ingreso directo a la URL donde se encuentra que sería ecuservicechile.lc/logica/créditos/créditos_disponibles.php si me retorna los valores correspondientes, pero si hago la llamada a dicha función mediante Ajax desde portal.ecuservicechile.lc/ordenes no me retorna nada.

Archivo créditos_disponibles.php RUTA ecuservicechile.lc/logica/créditos/créditos_disponibles.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
class CreditosDisponibles {
    public function Creditos(){
        $con = new Conexion();
        
        if(isset($_SESSION['idusuario'])){
            $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("creditos","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($_SESSION['idusuario']));
            $creditos = $datos[0]['creditos'];
        }
        return $creditos;
    }       
    
    
}
$creditos = new CreditosDisponibles();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $html1 = $creditos->Creditos(); 
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);    
}
?>
```

Archivo footer.php dentro de portal.ecuservicechile.lc/recursos/footer.php
¿A que puede deberse este problema?, será que no se están compartiendo las sesiones entre ambos VirtualHost?

```
function creditos(){        
        var action = 'fetch_data';              
        $.ajax({  
            url:"<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/creditos/creditos_disponibles.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ action:action},          
            success:function(data){   
                $('#creditos').html(data.html1);
                
            }
        }); 
    }
```